# duplicate library issue in XCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have been facing an issue in my project when I build my project.

**I integrated a third party framework which contains same JSONModel library which I have used in my Project. So it causes duplicity when project is build.**

Is there any way to solve without removing JSONModel from my project.

**Note:** I have not defined -all_load flag in 'Other linker flags' in build settings.

Any help is appreciable.

Comment: How you are including them, through cocoa pods, carthage or manually?

Comment: I have integrated JSONModel using Cocoapods.

Comment: how about other library?

Comment: In Objective C there is no concept called namespace. So if you are adding JSONModel Library from two sources it will show duplicate. The best way is to remove duplicate library or remove the reference from the target which you are using to build.

Comment: Other library I've integrated uses JSONModel. That's why I am getting duplicate library error.

Comment: It's the problem with the library. If they are importing `JSONModel` entirely, they should have renamed the files to add a prefix. There are no good solutions right now.